# How to prevent Hibernate formula annotation of adding table name before reserved words?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have my class mapped as follow:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    private String formulatedProp;

    @Formula(value="(SELECT ',' + coalesce(a.description,a.code) 
                    FROM another_table a 
                    WHERE a.order_id=id FOR XML PATH(''))")
    public String getFormulatedProp() {
        return formulatedProp;
    }
}
```

The formula's SQL query is fine when executing on its own. But when Hibernate generates the query to fetch an Order, it appends table's alias to `FOR` and `XML` words. So it tries to execute a query like

```
SELECT ',' + coalesce(a.description,a.code) 
    FROM another_table a 
    WHERE a.order_id=order0_.id order0_.FOR order0_.XML PATH('')
```

Which is obviously wrong. How can I make this work?
Environment: **Hibernate 3.6**, **SQL-Server 2008**

*P.S. I know that a custom dialect can be a solution, but I prefer not to go that direction.*

Comment: Try externalize your logic to function (CREATE FUNCTION).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same solution that I have written in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26907699/825061

The short answer is extend the hibernate dialect class that you use and register your new reserved words.

Comment: My preference at the time was to not use custom dialect (see the P.S. in the question), so this is not an answer to the question but worth a +1 IMHO :-). I am not even in the same job ATM ;-) but this may help people landing in this page anyway.

Comment: I have not noticed the P.S.. Thanks for the +1.