# Hibernate @formula is not supportinng Cast() as int for teradata database

Tags: hibernate, formula

I am using

```
@Formula("cast(item_code as \"int\")")
```

to cast a `String` column to `int`

but `hibernate` is generating the query as

```
and cast(this_.item_code as this_."int")=?
```

How do i get rid of the `alias` in front of `int` ?

I tried :

`@Formula("cast(item_code as "int")")`  and `@Formula("cast(item_code as int)")`

but still the same error . How do i cast the `String` to `int` ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 9):

I have resolved an issue similar to yours. I extended the hibernate Dialect class for my database.

```
public class Oracle10gDialectExtended extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public Oracle10gDialectExtended() {
        super();
        /* types for cast: */
        registerKeyword("int");
        // add more reserved words as you need
    }
}
```

Set 'hibernate.dialect' property with this new class. Now your @Formula will work.

Comment: I have `@Formula` containing subselect with `listagg(...) within group ...` and had similar problem with `within` clause but `registerKeyword("within")` unfortunately didn't help. However, I finally used own string aggregation function and didn't dig deeper into cause of this Hibernate behavior.

Comment: and register with all lower case. Wasted 2 hour to debug this.

Comment: Corresponding Spring Boot property: spring.jpa.database-platform

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```java
@Formula("cast(item_code as NUMERIC(1,0))")
```

The problem is that the dialect you are using does not recognize `int` as a Type (see *org.hibernate.dialect.isTypeNameRegistered()*).

You can either use the exact type based on your dialect (e.g. PostgreSQL uses `int4` but DB2, Ingres and H2 uses `integer` ...) or you can use `NUMERIC(1,0)` because everything what is followed by parentheses is considered to by a Function or a Keyword (see *org.hibernate.sql.Template.isFunctionOrKeyword()*).