# hibernate @Formula about 'convert(date)'

Tags: java, hibernate

I am Using SqlServer 2012 and my Entity is

```
public class Something {

    private Date rq;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "rq")
    @Formula("CONVERT(DATE,rq)")
    public Date getRq() {
        return Rq;
    }

    public void setRq(Date rq) {
     this.Rq = rq;
    }
}
```

**Hibernate debug log :**

```
Hibernate: 
select
    CONVERT(dnypowergr0_.DATE,
    dnypowergr0_.rq) as formula0_ 
from
    db.dbo.something dnypowergr0_
```

I want to get the result of 'rq' that can truly 'convert' but as the log shows, the first argument of 'convert' was added an alias of the table, So this sql is error.

Have I written wrong code or used part of '@Formula' ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to make hibernate to do not insert table alias where it is not needed. But there is a workaround. 
You can define a transient attribute (something like `convertedRq`) and convert value in Java. In this case `rq` will contain pure value of `rq` field, `convertedRq` will be calculated on fly.

Update: solution was posted here [Hibernate @formula is not supportinng Cast() as int for teradata database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679818/hibernate-formula-is-not-supportinng-cast-as-int-for-teradata-database/26907699#26907699) :

```
public class Oracle10gDialectExtended extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public Oracle10gDialectExtended() {
        super();
        /* types for cast: */
        registerKeyword("int");
        // add more reserved words as you need
    }
}
```

(c) Sergio M C Figueiredo