# Using a reserved word in @Formula annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to cast a string column to Integer.

```
    @Formula("CAST(pContactNumber as UNSIGNED)")
    private Integer contactNumber;
```

But Hibernate treats `UNSIGNED` word as `account0_.UNSIGNED`.
Any suggestion how to prevent this.

I have gone through following answer.
[Hibernate @formula is not supportinng Cast() as int for teradata database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679818/hibernate-formula-is-not-supportinng-cast-as-int-for-teradata-database/26907699#26907699)

But can someone explain where you use this extended Oracle10gDialect in spring configuration.

Comment: not Spring, you must reassign `hibernate.dialect` to the created `Oracle10gDialectExtended` (or the extension of the one you're using). You can change your dialect in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file....

Comment: @JordiCastilla It is possible to set `hibernateProperties` to `LocalSessionFactoryBean` using Spring configuration.

Comment: @v.ladynev Can you write this suggestion as an answer so that i can up vote it.

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hibernate.dialect` can be set using the `hibernateProperties` property of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.example.CustomOracle10gDialect</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

It is for Hibernate 5, because using the package `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`, for Hibernate 4 you need to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.