# Sorting expression in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity class where objectId is alphanumeric string

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CASE_INFO")
public class CaseInfo {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID")
  private String objectId;
}
```

I also have the following repository

```
@Repository
public interface CaseInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<CaseInfo, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CaseInfo> { }
```

Now when I make a query based on Specification and Pageable objects like this

```
Specification<CaseInfo> specification = (Specification<CaseInfo>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.and();
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 25, Sort.by("objectId"));
caseInfoRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
```

I want to be able to sort result based on CaseInfo.objectId numerically so that the order by in sql query would look something like this

```
... order by to_number(OBJECT_ID) ...
```

If I do something like

```
PageRequest.of(0, 25, Sort.by("objectId"))
```

it orders alphabetically so that "100" is before "2" which is wrong for my use case.

I found https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query where it uses

```
JpaSort.unsafe("LENGTH(name)")
```

but this does not seem to work because if I do

```
PageRequest.of(0, 25, JpaSort.unsafe("to_number(objectId)"))
```

It gives error message "No property to found for type CaseInfo! Did you mean 'id'?"

Does anybody know a way to give custom expression to Sort object?

Comment: Please include actual usage.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Show the code where you are using something and it is not working because of some reasons. Remember to include those "reasons" as well.....

Comment: I know this is NOT the answer to your question but is it simpler to make objectId as Long instead of String?

Comment: Yeah probably, but I was hoping there would be an easy solution with spring-jpa

Comment: What I believe that even though you can find some sort of solution in the higher layer but the data is not indexed for sorting in the data layer. The performance would be horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a formula field casting the string value to the numeric one and then sort by this field or use default implementation `findAll(Pageable pageable)`:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CASE_INFO")
public class CaseInfo {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID")
  private String objectId;

  @Formula(value = "CAST(OBJECT_ID AS NUMERIC(10, 0))")
  private int numObjectId;
}
```

Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface CaseInfoRepository extends 
                 JpaRepository<CaseInfo, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CaseInfo> {

    // sort by formula field 
    List<CaseInfo> findAllByOrderByNumObjectId(Pageable pageable);
}
```

There is a [trick with using `CAST` function in `@Formula`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679818/hibernate-formula-is-not-supportinng-cast-as-int-for-teradata-database) -- it is very likely to fail when casting to `INT`, `INTEGER`, `BIGINT` but it works when casting to `NUMERIC(10, 0)`.

`Numeric` also should be large enough to contain the value within the string after cast otherwise an integer overflow may occur.