# Spring's Pageable with custom Sort using SQL function

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, criteria-api

So I got the following JPA repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Foo> {}
```

And I am querying it with the Specification interface and PageRequest:

```
final Specification<Foo> spec = ...
final PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(direction, order));
return fooRepo.findAll(spec, pageRequest)
```

Ist there a way to apply a function to the sorting algorithm so for example the sql of `Sort.by("NAME", ASC)`

```
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

will be replaced with:

```
ORDER BY TRIM(NAME) ASC
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939687/sorting-expression-in-spring-data-jpa