# Hibernate/Spring Data JPA is not able to identify WITHIN keyword in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `@Formula` annotation for one of the property in my Entity/Pojo class. At runtime it is creating one query to fetch the result and it is throwing ERROR  `ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword` as it is not able to identify `WITHIN` as a keyword.

**Marks.java**

```
@Formula("(SELECT CASE WHEN dis_order IS NULL THEN (SELECT listagg(qpm.displayed_order,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY qpm.displayed_order) FROM que_post_mark qpm WHERE qpm.es_id = es_id AND qpm.sez_id = sez_id GROUP BY qpm.es_id, qpm.sez_id) ELSE NULL END FROM dual)")
private String childItemsDisplayedOrder;
```

Generated Query is like below:

```
select marks0_.*,
(SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN marks0_.displayed_order IS NULL THEN (SELECT
            listagg(qpm.displayed_order,
            ', ') marks0_.WITHIN 
        GROUP (ORDER BY
            qpm.displayed_order) 
        FROM
            que_post_mark qpm 
        WHERE
            qpm.es_id  = marks0_.es_id  
            AND qpm.sez_id = marks0_.sez_id 
        GROUP BY
            qpm.es_id ,
            qpm.sez_id) 
        ELSE NULL 
    END 
FROM
    dual) as formula2_0_ 
from
    MARKS marks0_ 
where
    marks0_.es_id =?
```

It is identifying `WITHIN` as column and appending alias name like `marks0_.WITHIN`

I am using below versions:

```
 spring-boot-starter-web = 1.4.0.RELEASE, spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.2 ,hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.1.3' hibernate-core:jar:5.1.3, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar
```

I tried to lower those jar versions to make it work but it didn't work.

Error Stacktrace is like below:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    ... 136 common frames omitted
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you remove the alias on `marks0_.WITHIN ` can you run the generated query in your database front-end?

Comment: @AlanHay If I remove the alias(marks0_.)  and run in SQL developer, the query is working as expected.

Comment: See this question looks like it doesn't recognise the keyword WITHIN. You can fix easily by creating a custom dialect as outlined in the given answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335509/how-to-prevent-hibernate-formula-annotation-of-adding-table-name-before-reserved

Comment: Although I see however in the comments that someone tried that specifically for WITHIN and it didn't work. My preference is to keep such complexities out of the Java code and handle at the database by means of a database view. You can then map the data from the view to your entity by using `@SecondaryTable`. The `childItemsDisplayedOrder` fields becomes just like any other field then. You will need to make it `Integer` type rather than `int` however to prevent unwanted inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by extending the hibernate Dialect class as mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679818/hibernate-formula-is-not-supportinng-cast-as-int-for-teradata-database/26907699#26907699)

```
public class Oracle10gDialectExtended extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public Oracle10gDialectExtended() {
        super();
        registerKeyword("within"); //Keyword has to be in lowercase.
    }
}
```

Set 'hibernate.dialect' property with this new class.

```
Properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "com.example.Oracle10gDialectExtended");
```

Comment: Or in Spring boot: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.example.Oracle10gDialectExtended`